# How do I change the content of recycler view in a fragment when a different tab is selected?

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-tabs

I have tried to create tabs dynamically using material design, Number of tabs will change according to the size of arraylist. I created only one fragment class to display under all the tabs. In Fragment class layout contains a recyclerview. The recyclerview should update based on the tabs.

```
enter code here

    arrayList.add("Greece");
    arrayList.add("Germany");
    arrayList.add("France");

    arrayList1.add("United States");
    arrayList1.add("United Kingdom");
    arrayList1.add("India");

    tabString.add("ONE");
    tabString.add("TWO");

    for(String st:arrayList)
    {
        temp.add(st);
    }




    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        int scrollposition=0;
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            scrollposition=position;
            if (positionOffsetPixels==0)
            {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("POSITION",position);
                ListFragment listFragment=new ListFragment();
                listFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            if (state==viewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
            {
                if(scrollposition==0) {
                    temp.clear();
                    for (String st : arrayList1) {
                        temp.add(st);
                        Log.v("MainActivity","aaa temp.add() : "+st);
                    }
                    ListFragment.adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    temp.clear();
                        for (String st : arrayList) {
                            temp.add(st);
                            Log.v("MainActivity","aaa temp.1add() : "+st);
                        }
                    ListFragment.adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }
        }
    });




}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    for(String cat: tabString)
    {
        adapter.addFragment(new ListFragment(), cat);
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title,int i) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
```

Comment: You have only one fragment for all your tabs ? What's the point of having tabs then ?

Comment: You already have an arraylist that controls the tablist and you want the tabs to control the recyclerview. So why not make the recyclerview be controlled by the same arraylist? So when arraylist is modified, create reset the adapters for the tabs and the recyclerview

Comment: I have only one fragment, which contains a recyclerview.  Whwn im swiping between the tabs , the content in recyclerview should change. @DavidSeroussi

Comment: Tabs arraylist(tabString) will be same always. when stab1 is selected arrayList should display or arrayList1 should display. Please guys... help me out on this. I hope you understand my problem